# Program not giving result expected to find duplicate in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have to find any duplicate element in arraylist before adding it into the arraylist. But it not giving the correct output. Both compilation and running doesn't give any errors.

```
public class MyDuplicateEntry {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        String[] strArr = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "four", "five"};
        ArrayList<String> unique = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String str : strArr) {
            if (!unique.add(str)) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate Entry is: " + str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could format your code? What's with the greater than signs? This is completely unreadable.

Comment: changed without > sign

Comment: Formatting is still ugly and does not fit standards.

Comment: @user2947572 Not really a problem, but bad formatting has nothing to do with being new here on SO. There exist Java Code Conventions which describe how code should be formatted. It's easier for everybody to read code from others when all are following these conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst  `java.util.ArrayList.add()` does return a boolean, this is hard-coded to always be true.

You seem to have made the assumption it will return false if the element is already in the list - this is not the case.

You will have to check that manually, see `ArrayList.contains()`.

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    String[] strArr = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "four", "five" };
    ArrayList<String> unique = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String str : strArr) {
        if (unique.contains(str)) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate Entry is: " + str);
        } else {
            unique.add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also consider using a `Set<String>` instead, as these are optimised for checking `contains()` - I would suggest a simple `HashSet<String>`.

Not only is this optimised, but it means you can check the return code of add, as this will return false if the element is already in the set:

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    String[] strArr = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "four", "five" };
    HashSet<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();

    for (String str : strArr) {
        if (! unique.add(str)) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate Entry is: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes

See javadoc on [`ArrayList.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) for details on always returning true.